# Disable YouTube AutoPlay on Home Feature

Tags: youtube

I'm having trouble disabling YouTube's "[AutoPlay on Home](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7640367)" feature on my wife's phone/account. I've followed the instructions provided on Google's support site, but when I reach the settings for "Autoplay", there is no "AutoPlay on Home" option to change (see below).

*ex. YouTube Missing AutoPlay on Home*

[image: YouTube Missing AutoPlay on Home]

I believe she is running v14.23.50 of the YouTube app for Android 9 on a Pixel 3 phone.

Can I somehow get to this setting? Should I report this to YouTube?

Comment: Just as feedback, running YT v14.23.50 on a Samsung and this option still appears for me.

Comment: It's weird because my phone (Pixel 3XL) has the option. So, I wonder if there is something with her account that it's not available.